# Acumatica ERP redirect by condition after the page has been loaded

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Is there any way to redirect from one custom page to another in case of some conditions when the first page is opened?

I have tried using `PXRedirectByScreenIDException` with `RowSelected` events but the exception is not being handled and redirect is not working.

```
protected void PrimaryView_RowSelected(PXCache sender,PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
     if(some_expression)
     {
          throw new PXRedirectByScreenIDException("II999999", PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Base, true);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Acumatica features work only in a narrow range of context. I noticed that `Redirection Exception` always work when executed in the context of an `Action Event Handler` . Presumably when executing those handlers the framework wraps the call around a catch block that specifically catch those redirection exception types and execute the redirection. In other contexts it probably doesn't catch this specific type and that results in a partially unhandled exception.

So my idea to redirect on page load is to throw the redirection exception inside an action event handler. The action need to be called from the UI context though otherwise it will still be unhandled. So I'll use JavaScript to call the action from UI on page load.

Graph extension that throws the redirection exception in the context of an action event handler:

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
  public PXAction<SOOrder> Redirect;

  [PXButton]
  public virtual IEnumerable redirect(PXAdapter adapter)
  {
      throw new PXRedirectByScreenIDException("SO302000", PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Base, true);

      return adapter.Get();
  }
}
```

I used `Add Controls` to add the JavaScript control. For new pages (not customizing existing pages) it's generally easier to use `Edit ASPX` to add the JavaScript. The JavaScript function calls the redirection action event handler in the graph extension.

```
function Redirect_Initialize() { px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("redirect"); }
```

[image]

Last step is to call the JavaScript method when the page loads. I used `CommandPerformed` because I know from experience it will be reliably called. You could try `Initialize` or other types of `Load` events as the JavaScript entry point but I had less luck with those.

I tested this complete solution and it did redirect on load. Maybe it might perform too many callbacks when your condition will not end in a redirection, you'll have to test that and pick another entry point if necessary.

If no suitable entry point is found I would use a global JavaScript variable as a flag so that it calls the graph action event handler only once. Repeatedly calling a JavaScript function has very low overhead, repeatedly calling back the server (IIS/ASP.Net) carry a huge penalty.

[image]

Comment: We have decided to move the Redirection logic to OnBeforePersist event handler, which will be added from PXViewExtensionAttribute. The reason is to simplify the process of the application of these validations and redirection to the custom screens.

Comment: Actually I missed the part where you mentioned from one custom page. For custom page there is possibility to have Load events in ASPX.CS file so is much more easier to hook on load then for customized page: asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/06/redirect-on-page-load.html