# I want to have a validation on my Custom Screen Setup

Tags: acumatica

I want to implement on and off switch feature on my acumatica custom setup screen.

Let's say I want to implement:

`feature1`

`feature2`

`feature3`

When I tick feature1, the corresponding screens with that Feature, its okay to me if it is still visible on the sitemap, or when a user enter to that screen it will prompt the user that the module is not available or not setup for the instance.

I'm using the constructor with the same ClassName as the GraphName like

```cs
public MyGraphClassName()
{
    throw new PXException("Error goes here for the Initialization method");
}
```

But when I do this, the screen where the DAC was applied is also giving an error, whereas it must still continue because it is only a partial of that screen. How will I do it?, I've also done using _RowSelected() event, it seems not working. I'm lost.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning behind 'partial of that screen'. Throwing exception in graph constructor could be used to block access to a screen, it's a valid pattern. If you want the screen to load but hide some elements you'll have to call PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible / Action.SetVisible. If you want a dialog prompt or redirect when the page loads this would require a workaround, you can use the trick explained here and use AskExt method to show dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811467/7376238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to throw a `PXSetupNotEnteredException` in the constructor. I have done this for various screens and so does Acumatica. Typical use is to block the user from using a page that requires the setup record to first be configured. In your case you can block because of a feature not configured or not enabled.

The example here is on the warehouse page. If the page is loaded and the Inventory preferences are not filled in then the page will throw a setup error which makes the entire page look like the image below. You can change the message as you need indicating your feature is not setup or enabled.

```
public class INSiteMaint : PXGraph<INSiteMaint, INSite>
{
    //..
    public PXSetup<INSetup> insetup;
    //..
    public INSiteMaint()
    {
        //Check for feature enabled or setup complete
        if (insetup.Current == null)
        {
            throw new PXSetupNotEnteredException(ErrorMessages.SetupNotEntered, typeof(INSetup), PXMessages.LocalizeNoPrefix(IN.Messages.INSetup));
        }
        //..

    //..
}
```

If the setup object is null (no IN Preferences configured) then the following warehouse page turns to this:

[image: thrown PXSetupNotEnteredException results]

It is also worth mentioning that in 2019R1 or greater you can control your features via the Acumatica enable/disable features by adding your own entry. If implemented correctly you can have Acumatica automatically hide the page from the sitemap (no need to implement PXSetupNotEnteredException). Currently there is no documentation on it (in beta) but guessing sometime this year there will be more detail available.